# Residual plot in regression

Tags: r

I have used following code in R:

```
k=lm(count~.-holiday-workingday,data=bike_new)
```

then created the following residual plot graph:

[image: residual plot]

You can see residual variability is not constant(non homogeneous).
regression assumption not met.

So what to do now? who has the answer? How to tackle this?

I need complete understanding.

Comment: You have misspecified the model (which we do not see). You will probably have to specify a different model and perhaps even account for heteroscedasticity (see `?gls`).

Comment: If my memory does not trick me, it is called heteroskedasticity. But honestly I think that your question does not belong here.

Comment: At least give more information on variables, or post some lines or a summary of your data!